# How to use PHP constant in routing YAML

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.4, symfony-routing

I'm using Symfony 3.4

I managed to get the PHP constant to work for a service (as described in the documentation). But I can't figure out how to get it to work in a routing file. Here's what I have so far.

Entity:

```php
namespace CompanyName\AppBundle\Entity\SomeDirectory;

class MyEntity
{
    public const STATUS__CREATED = 1;
}
```

routing.yml:

```yaml
view_my_entity_with_status_created:
  path:       /created/
  defaults:
    _controller: "AppBundle:SomeOtherDirectory/Something:index"
    status: !php/const CompanyName\AppBundle\Entity\SomeDirectory\MyEntity::STATUS__CREATED
```

`SomethingController`:

```php
public function indexAction(?int $status = null): Response
{
 // ...
}
```

From what I can tell the `!php/const` is being ignored since status is always null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't in Symfony 3.4.

Using `!php/const` in **routing** YAML configuration files was not enabled until Symfony 4.1.

While the feature was added to `YamlFileLoader` in 3.2, it was only enabled by default for the dependency injection component, not for the routing component.

[This](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/25293) is when the feature was merged.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your symfony version, this can be done with specific typo:

https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-2-php-constants-in-yaml-files

Before 3.2 it is not possible
from 3.2 to 3.4

```
arguments:
            - '@app.other_service'
            - !php/const:AppBundle\Entity\BlogPost::MUM_ITEMS
            - !php/const:Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel::VERSION
```

after 3.4:

```
arguments:
            - '@app.other_service'
            - !php/const AppBundle\Entity\BlogPost::MUM_ITEMS
            - !php/const Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel::VERSION
```

for your routing file:

```
# config/routes.yaml
blog_list:
    path:       /blog/{page}
    controller: AppBundle:SomeOtherDirectory/Something:index
    defaults:
        status: !php/const CompanyName\AppBundle\Entity\SomeDirectory\MyEntity::STATUS__CREATED
```

Comment: Tried your suggestion but it didn't work. I also tried to specify a constant that doesn't exist and didn't get an exception about it. So it seems that `!php/const` is still being ignored